# How to loop AVPlayer from 4 second to 8 second in swift 3?

Tags: ios, loops, swift3, avplayer

I have an  AVPlayer in swift 3 that plays video - the problem is that I want to use loop from A to B seconds (for example from 4 to 8 second)here is my codes for loop but didn't work

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.Player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.Player.play()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 4.0) {
                // check if player is still playing
                if self.Player.rate != 0 {
                    print("OK")
                    print("Player reached 4.0 seconds")
                    let timeScale = self.Player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale;
                    //        let seconds = kCMTimeZero
                    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( 8.0 , timeScale!)
                    self.Player.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
                    self.Player.play()


                }
            }
        }
    })
```

the problem is that this loop doesn't work and because of AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime the print("OK") won't work until the player has finished the movie

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options:

If you want gapless playback, you can start off by using:

Pre iOS 10: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/avloopplayer/Introduction/Intro.html

iOS 10+:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper

The pre-ios10 "solution" from apple does work, and is the only way I have gotten gapless looping since I target ios9.

If you are using that solution, you also need to either feed it an avplayeritem the right length or add to the solution to cut it up as you send it to the player.

For that, you can do something like how I changed apples code (sorry if its a bit sparse - just trying to show the main changes) - Basically adding in sending the track and the chunk of time to use, then make that an AVMutableCompositionTrack (I got rid of all the stuff for video - you will want to keep that in) :

```
class myClass: someClass {
    var loopPlayer:QueuePlayerLooper!

    var avAssetLength:Int64!
    var avAssetTimescale:CMTimeScale!
    var avAssetTimeRange:CMTimeRange!

    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem!

    var avAssetrack:AVAssetTrack!

    var compAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack!

    var uurl:URL!
    var avAsset:AVURLAsset!

    func createCMTimeRange(start:TimeInterval, end:TimeInterval) -> CMTimeRange {
        avAssetTimescale = avAssetTrack.naturalTimeScale

        let a:CMTime = CMTime(seconds: start, preferredTimescale: avAssetTimescale)
        let b:CMTime = CMTime(seconds: end, preferredTimescale: avAssetTimescale)
        return CMTimeRange(start: a, end: b)
    }


    func startLoopingSection() {
        loopPlayer = QueuePlayerLooper(audioURL: uurl, loopCount: -1, timeRange: createCMTimeRange(start: a_playbackPosition, end: b_playbackPosition))
        loopPlayer.start()

    }


}

//--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--==--

/*
 Copyright (C) 2016 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 See LICENSE.txt for this sample’s licensing information

 Abstract:
 An object that uses AVQueuePlayer to loop a video.
 */

 // Marked changed code with ++

class QueuePlayerLooper : NSObject, Looper {
    // MARK: Types

    private struct ObserverContexts {
        static var playerStatus = 0

        static var playerStatusKey = "status"

        static var currentItem = 0

        static var currentItemKey = "currentItem"

        static var currentItemStatus = 0

        static var currentItemStatusKey = "currentItem.status"

        static var urlAssetDurationKey = "duration"

        static var urlAssetPlayableKey = "playable"
    }

    // MARK: Properties

    private var player: AVQueuePlayer?

    private var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?

    private var isObserving = false

    private var numberOfTimesPlayed = 0

    private let numberOfTimesToPlay: Int

    private let videoURL: URL

    ++var assetTimeRange:CMTimeRange!
    ++let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    ++var currentTrack:AVAssetTrack!
    ++var assetTimeRange:CMTimeRange!



    // MARK: Looper

    required init(videoURL: URL, loopCount: Int, ++timeRange:CMTimeRange) {
        self.videoURL = videoURL
        self.numberOfTimesToPlay = loopCount
      ++self.assetTimeRange = timeRange
        super.init()
        super.init()
    }

    func start(in parentLayer: CALayer) {
        stop()

        player = AVQueuePlayer()
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        guard let playerLayer = playerLayer else { fatalError("Error creating player layer") }
        playerLayer.frame = parentLayer.bounds
        parentLayer.addSublayer(playerLayer)


        let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)

        ++currentTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        ++currentTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        ++try! compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(assetTimeRange, of: currentTrack, at: CMTimeMake(0, 1))





        videoAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [ObserverContexts.urlAssetDurationKey, ObserverContexts.urlAssetPlayableKey]) {
            /*
                The asset invokes its completion handler on an arbitrary queue
                when loading is complete. Because we want to access our AVQueuePlayer
                in our ensuing set-up, we must dispatch our handler to the main
                queue.
            */
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                var durationError: NSError?
                let durationStatus = videoAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: ObserverContexts.urlAssetDurationKey, error: &durationError)
                guard durationStatus == .loaded else { fatalError("Failed to load duration property with error: \(durationError)") }

                var playableError: NSError?
                let playableStatus = videoAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: ObserverContexts.urlAssetPlayableKey, error: &playableError)
                guard playableStatus == .loaded else { fatalError("Failed to read playable duration property with error: \(playableError)") }

                guard videoAsset.isPlayable else {
                    print("Can't loop since asset is not playable")
                    return
                }

                guard CMTimeCompare(videoAsset.duration, CMTime(value:1, timescale:100)) >= 0 else {
                    print("Can't loop since asset duration too short. Duration is(\(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset.duration)) seconds")
                return
            }

            /*
             Based on the duration of the asset, we decide the number of player 
             items to add to demonstrate gapless playback of the same asset.
             */
            let numberOfPlayerItems = (Int)(1.0 / CMTimeGetSeconds(videoAsset.duration)) + 2

            for _ in 1...numberOfPlayerItems {
                let loopItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: ++self.composition)
                self.player?.insert(loopItem, after: nil)
            }

            self.startObserving()
            self.numberOfTimesPlayed = 0
            self.player?.play()
        })
    }
}

}}
```

Comment: first I have video player not audio player - second I want to when user push the button for example the loop is starting from 4.0 second of the video to the 8.0 second

Comment: Both of the things I linked can do video by default. When you make an avplayerlooper, you can choose the time range right in the init. For the pre-ios10, you need to use something like the composition to tell it what section to play

Comment: But I can't see the 4.0 second and 8.0 second in your codes for loop video between these seconds

Comment: Oh, in my code, its the line "try! compAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(assetTimeRange, of: currentAudioTrack, at: CMTimeMake(0, 1))" - You pass it s CMTimeRange https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1462785-cmtimerangemake  , which takes a start and end CMTime https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtime , then you tell it what track you want a section of. in the ios10 built-in looping player also takes a CMTimeRange for input.

Comment: I got this but please edit your codes to the what I want

Comment: changed to show a sample implementation and the changes needed to apples code to take a time range

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me - it appears the poster would like you to write his app for him

Comment: @solenoid your approach seems logical but your code filled with error, i tried to solve them but the app getting crashed. so could you review your code once more? or just walk me trough it so i can resolve the problem. tnx in advance

Comment: @solenoid, Ok i fixed the problems and it works like a charm, tnx man. but there is no sound when video getting looped, how can i fix it?

Comment: @mehdok Are you setting up your audio session? Ex.         do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error with audio session", error)
        }  [i put this in viewDidLoad of the main viewController, though I suspect you can do it right when the app launches]

Comment: @solenoid ok i did that and it has no effect, by looking at the code you just cut the video track and playing it, am i right?

Comment: @mehdok cant open xcode at the moment, but you can make the composition have audio/video/and both iirc

Comment: I add the audio to composition by `let audio = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first
try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audio!, at: CMTimeMake(0, 1))`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediatypeaudio?changes=latest_major&language=objc  I would try to make it muxed, but I have not worked with it in that capacity before.

Answer (score 0):

You can add periodic time observer to monitor current time

```
let timeObserverToken = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: someInterval, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [unowned self] time in
    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime)
    if seconds >= 8.0 {
        // jump back to 4 seconds
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: what should I write for forInterval? because I used init() but I have received error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException